# Need a testing automation program for a Winforms application without source code

Tags: windows, data-recovery, automation

I am looking for (what I'm assuming) is a testing automation program. I need to harvest the data this application uses. I cannot access the database directly. I do not have the application's source code. I can only access the data by running the application, iterating through a known list of Record ID's, then scraping screens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use WinRunner or TestComplete but they're expensive and they have a learning curve but they are easier than using [DDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648712(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: After hours of review, looks like Ranorex is the best tool for my situation. I'm still considering TestComplete, tho'.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are looking to test and how good you are with scripting, [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3) is an amazing automation tool for standard windows controls and can be used for testing and reporting. It can be customized for just about any purpose and best of all, its free.
I use it primarily for automating simple tasks, but it is very often used for software testing.